# bash: run a command for n minutes, then SIGHUP it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, timeout

Is there any bash/linux command to launch a long-running command, then kill it after n minutes? I guess I could hack something up with perl using fork and kill, but does anyone know of something already out there?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

See the [timeout](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#timeout-invocation) command now in most GNU/Linux distros.

```
timeout -sHUP 10m command
```

The same functionality can be achieved with http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/timeout

Answer (score 20):

Try it with this one, it starts your command in the background, stores it's PID in $P, waits for some time and kills it with a `SIGHUP`.

```
yourCommand & PID=$!
sleep ${someMinutes}m
kill -HUP $PID
```

Cheers

PS: that assumes a sleep that knows about Nm (minutes), else, you might want to do some math :)

Comment: Thanks! This is essentially the perl I just wrote, but it's nice to see it as just a shell idiom. I'd still like a pre-built script, if anyone is aware of one, but I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 12):

```
n=5
some_command &
pid=$!
at now + $n minutes <<<"kill -HUP $pid"
```

The benefit of using `at` over waiting for `sleep` is that your script wont block waiting for the sleep to expire. You can go and do other things and `at` will asynchronously fire at the specified time.  Depending on your script that may be a very important feature to have.

Comment: I gave this +1 for the async feature, although blocking is what I had in mind.